# Regex to validate SQL script to allow only CREATE|ALTER|DROP for VIEW|PROCEDURE|TRIGGER

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, regex, validation

I have to validate SQL scripts for an automated database upgrade procedure.

I need to autorize only CREATE|ALTER|DROP function for only "PROCEDURE|TRIGGER|VIEW.

Presently I use this function with regex to validate :

```
Public Function ValidateScript(script as string) as Boolean
    Regex.IsMatch(script.Trim, "^(CREATE|ALTER|DROP)\\s+(PROCEDURE|TRIGGER|VIEW)")
End Function
```

But if the script contain 2 instructions like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XXX as ...
    Instruction1;
    Instruction2;
    ...
GO (OR ;)
DROP TABLE
GO (OR ;)
```

The validation return True

How can I validate scripts that contain many instructions ?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag the dbms you using! (SQL scripts are usually product specific.)

Comment: Split the script by the keyword GO, then analyze the validity of each node

Comment: Do you need to prevent whole match in your last script or only select compliant query (i.e. `CREATE PROCEDURE`)?

Comment: Sounds like you need a *parser*, not just a regex.

Comment: I must allow the execution of scripts for the creation of specific objects and prevent execution if they contain unauthorized instructions.
This is for batch processing and the user executing scripts will have all rights to the database.